# How to prove $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i2^{-i}$ converges almost surely?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $X_i$ are iid $\text{Ber}(\frac{1}{2})$, I wanted to show $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i2^{-i}$ converges almost surely, as $n\to\infty$.

I can see that it converges in distribution to $\text{Unif}[0,1]$ but I wanted to show almost sure convergence without using a limit that $S_n$ potentially may converge to.

**My ideas:**

Since $|X_i2^{-i}|\leq2^{-i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}2^{-i}<\infty$. Hence we can deduce $S_n$ converges as it is absolute convergent? But then I am not sure how to show almost sure convergence.

Now I am a bit clueless. Without using the definition of almost sure convergence I am not too sure how to otherwise prove almost sure convergence.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing more to be done. If $X_i(\omega) \in \{ 0,1\}$ for all $\omega$ the you have proved that $\sum X_i(\omega)2^{-i} <\infty$ **for every** $\omega$.